# What continues the sequence of integer pairs?

Tags: number-sequence

Given the following sequence of integer pairs:

> $(1,3), (2,4), (3,1), (?,?)$

Which of the following pairs takes the place of $(?,?)$?:

> $(-2,4)$
>   $(-1,4)$
>   $(-3,2)$
>   $(-1,3)$
>   $(-2,3)$

Note that I don't know the answer, and was hoping any of you could shed a light.

Comment: I've tried to clean up the formatting, but wasn't sure: were the first digits of the options meant to be negative, or were the dashes just pseudo-bullet points?

Comment: This seems like far too little information to determine a definite correct answer. Unless there's some super-clever thing I'm missing that nails it down, this is going to be a matter of guessing what pattern whoever wrote the question happened to be thinking of.

Comment: I am so sorry, the first digits were meant to be negative, completely slipped my mind, somehow. Corrected the OP

Comment: For the reasons above I don't think it's possible to give an actual *answer* to this question, but here for what it's worth is my best guess at what's in the mind of the person who wrote it: each of the two "steps" taken so far changes the parity of both numbers, and the next "step" needs to do likewise; the only one of the given pairs that does this is (-2,4). This is of course a *really unsatisfactory* answer, not least because it gives us no reason why (-2,4) would be better than say (0,0).

Comment: Solved. @bambozzler3000

Answer (score 3):

The three given points are part of

> an ellipse,
> $(1,3)$ being **centre**, $(2,4)$ and $ (3,1)$ being the ends of minor and major axis respectively.

[image: Ellipse points]

---

> The equation of ellipse is :$$5x^2+5y^2-36y-28x+6xy+52=0$$

---

> The only point which lies inside the ellipse is :  $(-1,4)$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is (-2,4) because the three given points form a right-angled triangle and when we tile the plane with copies of that triangle in the "obvious" way (-2,4) is the only one of the given points that's a vertex of one of these triangles:

[image]

Or because (-2,4) is the only one of the given answers that continues the pattern of having both coordinates change by an odd integer at each step.

The answer is (-1,4) because it's the only one of the answers that lies in the ellipse extracted from the given points by ABcDexter (in another answer to this question).

The answer is (-3,2) because this is the only one of the given answers that continues the pattern of having one coordinate change by exactly 1 at each step.

The answer is (-1,3) because this is the only one of the given answers that specifies the difference between two of the given points. (The vector from (3,1) to (2,4) is (-1,3).)

The answer is (-2,3) because, er, it's the only one of the given answers for which there's no plausible brief justification.

(In case it isn't obvious: I do not find any of these adequate reasons for picking one of the given answers over all the rest, nor do I expect anything else to be an adequate reason. The first of the ones above, as I mentioned in a comment, seems the least hopelessly useless one and might be the intended answer.)

Comment: That's a non-trivial answer and an amazing find also.

Comment: The real point of the answer is exactly that it's *not* amazing! There's so little to go on in the question that we shouldn't be surprised to find lots of comparably-plausible answers.

Comment: Yes, I second that this question is ambiguous. Shouldn't it be VTCed?

Comment: I would VTC except that as a moderator I can't: if I VTC a question then that just closes it immediately. I don't think this one is so obviously bad that I should be closing it unilaterally, especially as no one else seems to be VTCing it.

Comment: Okay, understood. I have raised a flag, maybe others who've answered feel the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the given pairs and **edited** question, I need to provide an updated answer. Earlier answer is

> (2, 4) and (1, 3). The reason is - the absolute difference between the pairs of numbers is 2

And an answer for edited question could be:

> (-2, 4)

As, the sequence of pairs follows as below:

> ( a,b) is the given odd numbered pair, then the immediate even pair is calculated as ( b-a, b+a ). With this logic next pair becomes( 1-3, 1+3 ) or (-2, 4).

Comment: A subtle problem: the problem says, "Which of the following pairs **takes** the place of…" where 'takes' is a singular verb instead of 'take', the plural verb, so we are most likely looking for one answer. (If you don't understand what I mean by this, consider 'The boy takes cookies from the jar' as opposed to 'The boys take cookies from the jar'.)

Comment: @boboquack grammatically either pairs take orpair takes is correct, but not a mix resulting of those.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you just said. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Apep agreed. As which can mean a plural form, I wish to proceed with that ( a possible case of benefit of doubt!?)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend drawing inferences from the exact wording, which has been changed (for clarity) from that originally posted. (But, on the grammatical question, boboquack is correct; as currently written the question implies that we are looking for a single pair.)

Comment: [@MeaCulpaNay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56519/what-continues-the-sequence-of-integer-pairs#comment174074_56521) The numerical agreement actually matches the words *which ... takes* (vs the equally grammatical but plural *which ... take*).

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Your proposed rule correctly describes the first step given but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

> $(−2,4)$

**Solution**

> The first digit of each set is incremental. It starts 1, 2, 3 therefore the next digit is likely to be 4.
>
> The second digit of each are all numbers from 1 to 4 but in a seemingly random order. There is 3, 4 and 1. The only remaining number is 2.
>
> So now we have 4 and 2 $(4,2)$. None of these pairs match and they are all negative values. We are only given a choice of negative numbers.
>
> Negative values are opposite to positive values. I'm guessing since we are inverting the position on the number line we can also invert the order of the numbers. Therefore + becomes - and 4,2 becomes 2,4.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pair:

> $(−1,3)$

Reasoning:

> Given three pairs forms right triangle. It is the only pair from five to choose that forms right triangle together with previous two pairs.